# Replacing stack vs. static variable with instance of struct containing const member

Tags: c++, static

Using gcc version 4.4.3 as follows:

```
gcc -g -x c++ -lstdc++ -std=c++98 -o ./main ./main.cpp
```

this code in main.cpp compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A()
    : m_flag(false)
    {
    }

    const bool m_flag;
};

static A aa = A();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;

    // Not static = copy OK
    A b( a );
    A c = b;
    A d = A();

    // Static = copy not OK
    // aa = A();
}
```

But if I uncomment `aa = A();` I get:

```
./main.cpp: In member function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)':
./main.cpp:4: error: non-static const member 'const bool A::m_flag', can't use default assignment operator
./main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
./main.cpp:24: note: synthesized method 'A& A::operator=(const A&)' first required here
```

Why does the default copy construction and copy assignment work for copies on the stack but not when replacing the non-const `static` with a copy?

Comment: The default assignment operator is never invoked in your program, except for the failing line. On which line do you *think* the default assignment operator is  being invoked successfully?

Comment: +1 for providing a minimal, complete program that demonstrates the problem you describe. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: I sure hope you're not invoking g++ like that all the time...seems very cumbersome (unless it's generated by your make system like that, which also seems weird).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
 const bool m_flag;
 ...
 aa = A();  // invokes 'A::operator =(const A&)`
```

which invokes default `operator =`. Modifying `const` member is a trivial error.

```
A b( a );   // all invoke `A::A(const A&)`
A c = b;  
A d = A();
```

invokes default copy constructor (not `operator =` as you assume), where `m_flag` is assigned a new value at the initialization itself.